# Shifting Specific Rows (Second Row Onwards)

Tags: python, pandas

I need to shift the columns on a pandas dataframe (all rows but the first one).

Tried loc and shift but it fills `Exports` column with `NaN`.
![enter image description here][1]

```
import pandas as pd
psd = pd.read_table("psd.html")
psd.loc[1:] = psd.loc[1:].shift(2,axis=1)
```

[Here is the link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/172iFmqRB99az0UAcyU8h9xpRZchV5pOJ/view?usp=sharing) to the html file in google drive.

`psd.info()` before shifting

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 17 columns):
 #   Column                 Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                 --------------  -----  
 0   Commodity              3 non-null      object 
 1   Year                   3 non-null      object 
 2   Country                3 non-null      object 
 3   Area Harvested         3 non-null      object 
 4   Beginning Stocks       3 non-null      object 
 5   Production             3 non-null      object 
 6   Imports                3 non-null      object 
 7   Total Supply           3 non-null      object 
 8   Exports                3 non-null      int64  
 9   Use Dom. Consumption   3 non-null      object 
 10  Loss Dom. Consumption  3 non-null      object 
 11  Domestic Consumption   3 non-null      object 
 12  Ending Stocks          3 non-null      object 
 13  Total Distribution     3 non-null      object 
 14  Stocks-To-Use          1 non-null      float64
 15  Yield                  1 non-null      float64
 16  Unit Description       0 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(3), int64(1), object(13)
memory usage: 536.0+ bytes
```

Comment: what is the problem? you done correctly. You displayed only from the second row onwards. After what you wrote, display entire dataframe with `psd`. P.S - your dataframe is different from the excel you showed in image

Comment: Thanks Jure. The thing is: something weird happened, look at the column "Exports". It shows NaN. Have an idea about what happens? Sorry about the different images, I made the second one in Excel with less data just to make it easier to understand the concept.

Comment: Thanks Richie. I've just shared it. Edited the original post so you can see it at the bottom.

Comment: you should always provide a way for others to reproduce the problem... read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thanks Richie. Just uploaded the sample file used on my google drive:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/172iFmqRB99az0UAcyU8h9xpRZchV5pOJ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a bug while shifting columns of different dtype, but here's a work-around.

```
psd = pd.read_table("psd.html", dtype='object')

psd = psd.applymap(lambda x:
    x.replace(',', '') if isinstance(x, str) else x)

psd.loc[1:] = psd.loc[1:].shift(2, axis=1)


psd.loc[:, 'Area Harvested':] = psd.loc[:, 'Area Harvested':].astype(float)

print(psd)
psd.info()
```

Output

```
  Commodity       Year        Country  Area Harvested  Beginning Stocks  \
0    Cotton  2020/2021      Argentina           425.0            1229.0
1       NaN        NaN         Brazil          1550.0           14024.0
2       NaN        NaN  United States          3644.0            7250.0

   Production  Imports  Total Supply  Exports  Use Dom. Consumption  \
0      1300.0      5.0        2534.0    425.0                 525.0
1     12000.0     25.0       26049.0   9200.0                3000.0
2     17064.0      3.0       24317.0  14600.0                2500.0

   Loss Dom. Consumption  Domestic Consumption  Ending Stocks  \
0                    0.0                 525.0         1584.0
1                    0.0                3000.0        13849.0
2                   17.0                2517.0         7200.0

   Total Distribution  Stocks-To-Use   Yield  Unit Description
0              2534.0         166.74   666.0               NaN
1             26049.0         113.52  1686.0               NaN
2             24317.0          42.11  1020.0               NaN
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 17 columns):
 #   Column                 Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------                 --------------  -----
 0   Commodity              1 non-null      object
 1   Year                   1 non-null      object
 2   Country                3 non-null      object
 3   Area Harvested         3 non-null      float64
 4   Beginning Stocks       3 non-null      float64
 5   Production             3 non-null      float64
 6   Imports                3 non-null      float64
 7   Total Supply           3 non-null      float64
 8   Exports                3 non-null      float64
 9   Use Dom. Consumption   3 non-null      float64
 10  Loss Dom. Consumption  3 non-null      float64
 11  Domestic Consumption   3 non-null      float64
 12  Ending Stocks          3 non-null      float64
 13  Total Distribution     3 non-null      float64
 14  Stocks-To-Use          3 non-null      float64
 15  Yield                  3 non-null      float64
 16  Unit Description       0 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(14), object(3)
memory usage: 536.0+ bytes
```

Comment: Thank you very much Richie! Worked perfectly!